# Banach Subalgebras: Spectrum

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory, banach-algebras

Given a Banach algebras:
$$1_\mathcal{A}=1_\mathcal{B}\in\mathcal{A}\subseteq\mathcal{B}$$

For C*-algebras it holds:
$$A\in\mathcal{A}:\quad \sigma_\mathcal{A}(A)=\sigma_\mathcal{B}(A)$$

But what about in general:
Are there elements for which this fails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course $\sigma_B(T) \subset \sigma_A(T)$ for any $T \in A$.  But in general, they need not be equal.  For example, take $B = C(\mathbb{T})$, with $\mathbb{T}$ the unit circle in the complex plane.  If we consider the identity function $z$, then $\sigma_B(z) = \mathbb{T}$, but consider the restriction to the subalgebra $A$ of $B$ which consists of functions with continuous extension to the disk and analytic on the interior (i.e. the closure of the subalgebra generated by 1 and $z$).  Then we have $\sigma_A(z) = \bar{\mathbb{D}}$, the closed disk.  In general, larger algebras can have 'holes' in spectra relative to the smaller subalgebra.  See theorem 1.2.8 from Murphy's C*-algebra book for the precise statement about holes and more on this example.

Comment: Great!!! Thats exactly what I was hoping for. Thank you very much!!! :)